# SFDC using my IP instead of SFDC IP range

Tags: integration

I am working on an integration between SFDC and an on premise system. This on premise system needs to be accessed from inside of SFDC.  When SFDC API call hits the on premise application it shows my IP address instead of the request coming from SFDC IP List. 
Due to this the reverse proxy is blocking the request, how can i make sure that the request to the on premise application comes from SFDC IP's instead of my IP ?

Thanks
A. S.

Comment: Is the API call happening in Apex or JavaScript?

Comment: I have setup a custom Web Tab for this on premise application.

Comment: So then the API call isn't coming from Salesforce, it's coming from the IP of the browser/client?

Comment: yes, its coming from the IP of the browser/client.

Comment: Only way to do it then would be to modify the on premise application to send its web calls through an Apex RemoteAction if it's inside SFDC, but you haven't provided any information about what control you have over the on premise application code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use java script or any sort of client side scripting the request is made from your browser to on premise system. Due to this on premises system will get the request from client that your browser. If you want to avoid that then

1) You will need to call those on premise system APIs from apex
2) Wrap apex code created above in rest of soap api
3) And from your web tab/page your will need to call sfdc API created in step 2

Note that now your SFDC api created in step 2 will receive client IP but on premise system will always receive SFDC IP